# How to place element across table cells while retaining the background border?

Tags: html, html-table

like this picture, I want to place black div between two cells vertically.

[image]

If I use rowspan, the border between cells will disappear.
I don't want border to disappear.
Should I use css grid and div?

Answer (score 1):

You could make `td` elements `position: relative` then place a `div` in the top-most `td` you want it to appear in. The `div` would be something like `position: absolute; height: 100%; top: 50%; width: 70%; left: 15%; background: #000'`.

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. You would also need to set the `z-index` on the div to something higher than td, to avoid the bottom cell border going over the div.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a way to create 2 divs at the bottom and top of the cells is suitable